# remove n consecutive elements from array, so that amplitude of remaining elements is minimal

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-programming, amplitude

Given array `A`, I need to remove `K` consecutive elements, so that the amplitude(difference between maximal and minimal elements) of the remaining elements will be minimal.
e.g `A=[3,5,1,3,9,8], K=4,`  the answer should be 1. I could remove `[3,5,1,3]`  to get 1.

I saw a similar post here: [Program to find minimal amplitude after removing consecutive elements from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68148191/program-to-find-minimal-amplitude-after-removing-consecutive-elements-from-array), someone commented about using prefix and suffix minimum and maximum, but I do not know what it means and how that would be helpful. If anybody could clarify/provide other suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n) solution with prefix/suffix minima/maxima:

```
def solution(A, K):
    pre = zip(acc(A, min, initial=inf),
              acc(A, max, initial=-inf))
    suf = list(zip(list(acc(A[::-1], min, initial=inf))[::-1],
                    list(acc(A[::-1], max, initial=-inf))[::-1]))
    return min(max(left[1], right[1]) - min(left[0], right[0])
               for left, right in zip(pre, suf[K:]))
```

For your example `A = [3,5,1,3,9,8]` we have the prefix minima/maxima and suffix minima/maxima:

```
pre: (∞,-∞) (3,3) (3,5) (1,5) (1,5) (1,9) (1,9)
suf:  (1,9) (1,9) (1,9) (3,9) (8,9) (8,8) (∞,-∞)
```

After aligning for `K = 4` you have:

```
pre:                         (∞,-∞) (3,3) (3,5) (1,5) (1,5) (1,9) (1,9)
suf:  (1,9) (1,9) (1,9) (3,9) (8,9) (8,8) (∞,-∞)
```

For example the pairing of `left = (3,5)` and `right = (∞,-∞)` corresponds to a left subarray `[3,5]` and right subarray `[]` after removing `[1,3,9,8]`. Where the minimum of left and right side is `min(3,∞)=3` and the maximum is `max(5,-∞)=5`, for an amplitude of `5-3=2`.

Ten random tests against naive brute force reference solution:

```
917 917 True
908 908 True
898 898 True
925 925 True
939 939 True
954 954 True
905 905 True
899 899 True
927 927 True
934 934 True
```

Whole code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLboMwELzzFXu0FaciSiOlSBxyziegqELEBKsGI2OqpD9Pd22cV1OfFmZ2Z3bs/uIa0623vZ2m2poWlJPWGaMHUG1vrIOyqsZ21KWTUA70lXheW7omUlRXh5@27I40I/yuGqMqOSTJUdYwGD06ZTq2E7DnWQJ4eishhx/VMxxLQKs6gdOUU6XOcSoXnnc7kVeeb7wlEbknDmONA7UaHKOpvvAtRZYtV4cXAnxGnnTCedH/VzhAswEr3Wg7kmFIZVrWrqA@q04NVRyWHvRAegXSA382UBsLxJopKOqDwsgErVnsM9JMeqs6x67hFmsBGwErAVh8CNiixDvx6Aq6Un3L@/ytHEbtMDG6wCiqSAov8iTRJV4XhwWs0HZsolOZ/oJtuzcq2M37UWqPFQoyUIv94YpcpWj78OHTZESPqfj6IcjAjGuGBf7dkdx/3tyv0tnxDmXnt8gilKZcwFeORdDbI2eT@lKee1mR1bu8HuN6fMvzUyaDoVVAXDB25PNQPk2/)):

```
from itertools import accumulate as acc
from math import inf
from random import choices

def solution(A, K):
    pre = zip(acc(A, min, initial=inf),
              acc(A, max, initial=-inf))
    suf = list(zip(list(acc(A[::-1], min, initial=inf))[::-1],
                    list(acc(A[::-1], max, initial=-inf))[::-1]))
    return min(max(left[1], right[1]) - min(left[0], right[0])
               for left, right in zip(pre, suf[K:]))

print(solution([3, 5, 1, 3, 9, 8], 4))

def naive(A, K):
    result = inf
    for i in range(len(A) + 1 - K):
        copy = A.copy()
        del copy[i : i+K]
        result = min(result, max(copy) - min(copy))
    return result

print(naive([3, 5, 1, 3, 9, 8], 4))

for _ in range(10):
    A = choices(range(1000), k=100)
    K = 50
    expect = naive(A, K)
    result = solution(A, K)
    print(expect, result, result == expect)
```